# How to query with unicode input value in Firebird 2.1?

Tags: firebird

I made a simple SELECT statement, like this:

```
select t.no_qult, t.desc_qult
from qualities_type t
where t.name_qult = 'Lỗi vải'
```

The field `name_qult` is UNICODE_FSS charset. Problem is it didn't work with unicode input value `Lỗi vải` (Vietnamese language), just work when I use plain text `Lá»—i váº£i`.
[image: firebird screen]

Does anyone know how to query with a unicode input value?

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the query? What connection character set did you specify?

Comment: I make a request from Android, using RESTful web service to get data from Firebird Database.

Comment: That is not really sufficient information, but look at the question I linked, you are likely using the wrong connection character set. And otherwise you will really need to post a [MCVE].

Answer (score -1):

Do not use literals. Don't put data into the query text, put it outside of query as "parameters".

It has a number of benefits, like more reliable parsing, more type-checking, more safety and often more speed (you can prepare query once, and then run it many times only changing parameters value).

How you code the parameters in SQL queries depends upon the library you use in your programming language for connecting to Firebird. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for some examples. The following are three often used conventions to try:

- `SELECT .... WHERE t.name_qult = ?`  -- natively supported by Firebird, index-based access to parameters
- `SELECT .... WHERE t.name_qult = :NAME_PARAM` -- BDE / Delphi style
- `SELECT .... WHERE t.name_qult = @NAME_PARAM` -- MS SQL / .Net style

I do not know which flavours are supported in languages and programs you use.
IB Expert uses Delphi libraries, hence using #2 option.
Java-written programs tent to use #1 option.

---

Additionally in your connection options check that the "connection charset" is set to UTF-8 or to come Vietnamese codepage that can transfer all those specific characters.

---

UNICODE_FSS charset is outdated. If possible, it would be better to move to UTF-8 charset wherever possible.